# Browse list in python and get data

Tags: python, html, api, youtube

I want to get the total number of views of a serie of videos on Youtube about a concrete topic.

I have this code, but it doesn't work because I am not getting the correct data from the list "videos". How can I browse this list and get the total views of the complete list?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.tools import argparser


# Set DEVELOPER_KEY to the API key value from the APIs & auth > Registered apps
# tab of
#   https://cloud.google.com/console
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSyB..........I"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

def youtube_search(options):
  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

  # Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
  # query term.
  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=options.q,
    part="id,snippet",
    maxResults=options.max_results
  ).execute()

  videos = []
  channels = []
  playlists = []

  # Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
  # matching videos, channels, and playlists.
  for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
    if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
      videos.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                 search_result["id"]["videoId"]))
    elif search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#channel":
      channels.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                   search_result["id"]["channelId"]))
    elif search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#playlist":
      playlists.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                    search_result["id"]["playlistId"]))

  print "Videos:\n", "\n".join(videos), "\n"
  ###################################
  ###################################
  ###HERE IS THE PROBLEM##########
  ###################################
  for video in videos:
    source = video
    response = urllib2.urlopen(source)
    html = response.read() #Done, you have the whole HTML file in a gigantic string

    wordBreak = ['<','>']  
    html = list(html)
    i = 0
    while i < len(html):
      if html[i] in wordBreak:
          html[i] = ' '
      i += 1

    #The block above is just to make the html.split() easier.

    html = ''.join(html)
    html = html.split()
    dataSwitch = False
    numOfViews = ''
    for element in html:
      if element == '/div':
        dataSwitch = False
      if dataSwitch:
        numOfViews += str(element)
      if element == 'class="watch-view-count"':
        dataSwitch = True

    print (numOfViews)
  ########################################
  ########################################
  #######################################

  print "Channels:\n", "\n".join(channels), "\n"
  print "Playlists:\n", "\n".join(playlists), "\n"


if __name__ == "__main__":
  argparser.add_argument("--q", help="Search term", default="la la land")
  argparser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=25)
  args = argparser.parse_args()

  try:
    youtube_search(args)
  except HttpError, e:
    print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```

Comment: As far as I see the videos is a list of strings, each of which is "title videoid" values. Do you even get anything as a result by doing `response = urllib2.urlopen(source)`?

Comment: No, you are rigth, this line causes an error, but I don't know how can I do that :/

Comment: I suggest you try to understand what's going on with this code line by line. You can see that the videos isn't actually made of URLs, but of the string "title videoid". This is where it happens in your code: 
`videos.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                                search_result["id"]["videoId"]))`